# Перенос данных(переменных) из C# в HTML

Tags: c#, html

Есть шаблон отчета на языке HTML и создана программа для расчетов на языке C#.
Нужно что бы значения из программы перетащить в шаблон HTML не знаю как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста.

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Расчет</title>  
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="top">ПРОТОКОЛ РАСЧЕТА</h1>
<p>
 X= <br />
 Y= <br />
 Z= <br />
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

и пример кода в C#

```
public static double x, y, z;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x=5;
    y=1;
    z=x+y;
}
```

Это примитивный пример но все же. Вот как можно предать значения X,Y,Z в уже готовый файл html.
и возможно ли передать данные из C# в HTML?
Помогите пожалуйста
Если не коректно задан вопрос оповестите я попытаюсь скоректировать его более понятно

Comment: Зависит от того как ваш html связан с с#. Можно передать, например через `string.Format`, при определённых условиях.

Comment: Если для связи используется ASPX, то можно так `X=<%=x%>;`

Comment: @nick_n_a сможете подробнее объяснить как сделать через первый вариант или любой пример если вам не сложно будет.

Comment: Можно через Razor, можно через XSLT, вам выбирать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способов сделать подобное существует множество. Это и Razor, и XSLT...
Всё зависит от исходных данных.
В каком виде ваш шаблон? Это просто текст разметки? Или некий объект, содержащий DOM?

Если в вашей власти выбрать/изменить способ представления шаблона, то я могу предложить использовать linq2xml. Т. к. xhtml является также well-formed xml.

```
int x = 5;
int y = 1;
int z = x + y;

XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
    new XElement(ns + "html", new XAttribute("lang", "ru"),
        new XElement(ns + "head",
            new XElement(ns + "meta", new XAttribute("charset", "utf-8")),
            new XElement(ns + "title", "Расчет")
        ),
        new XElement(ns + "body",
            new XElement(ns + "h1", new XAttribute("id", "top"), "ПРОТОКОЛ РАСЧЕТА"),
            new XElement(ns + "p",
                "X= " + x, new XElement(ns + "br"),
                "Y= " + y, new XElement(ns + "br"),
                "Z= " + z, new XElement(ns + "br")
            )
        )
    )
);

Console.WriteLine(doc); // doc.Save(...);
```

На мой взгляд, всё просто и понятно.
Этот способ гарантирует правильное экранирование всех символов и корректную разметку.
При добавлении новых элементов не забывайте указывать пространство имён (`ns`).

Comment: А как можно добавить изображение в html?

Comment: @Belial - не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Добавить можно разными способами. У вас вопрос по html или по C#?

Comment: Сам вопрос как через c# добавить изображение в html. Извините что через коментарий

Comment: @Belial - есть разные способы добавления изображения в html. Это может быть ссылка на картинку (абсолютный или относительный путь), это может быть base64-строка. Выберите способ (и отредактируйте вопрос), а я покажу, как это сделать в C#.

Comment: Извините за беспокойство сделал так же через XElement(ns+"img", new XAttribute("src", "../graf.jpg")) .  Спасибо за то что отозвались и ещё раз извините за беспокойство, просто получилось что  web не мог открыть изображение и через браузер открылось отлично. Еще раз извините.

Comment: @Belial - да, это правильный способ. Удачи!